# Asp.Net Core 3.1 Identity LinqToDB.Identity UserStore Problem

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have been trying to implement .Net Identity for my .Net Core 3.1 project. In my project, I am using LinqToDB to use Database. Such as, MySQL, MSSQL. I have implemented my Identity classes like AppUser, AppRole, AppUserClaim and have created them into my mssql database by using LinqToDB. The problem is that when the project is running, it returns an error that says like this.

GenericArguments[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Musvu.png), 'DevPlatform.Core.Domain.Identity.AppUser', on 'LinqToDB.Identity.UserStore`7[TKey,TUser,TRole,TUserClaim,TUserRole,TUserLogin,TUserToken]' violates the constraint of type 'TUser'.'

TypeLoadException: GenericArguments[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Musvu.png), 'DevPlatform.Core.Domain.Identity.AppUser', on 'LinqToDB.Identity.UserStore`7[TKey,TUser,TRole,TUserClaim,TUserRole,TUserLogin,TUserToken]' violates the constraint of type parameter 'TUser'.

I am getting this error in that code block;

```
 public static void AddDevPlatformAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.AddIdentity<AppUser, LinqToDB.Identity.IdentityRole>(options =>
        {
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 4;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;

            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;

            //TODO
            //options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true; 
            //options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
            //options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
            //options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3);

        }).AddLinqToDBStores(new DefaultConnectionFactory())
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie();

        // Uncomment the following lines to enable logging in with third party login providers

        JwtTokenDefinitions.LoadFromConfiguration(configuration);
        services.ConfigureJwtAuthentication();
        services.ConfigureJwtAuthorization();
    }
```

Here is my AppUser class that has inherited from IdentityUser class.

```
using DevPlatform.Core.Entities;
using LinqToDB.Identity;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace DevPlatform.Core.Domain.Identity
{

public class AppUser : IdentityUser<int>, IEntity
{
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    public int? CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public int? ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public int? StatusId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("UserDetail")]
    public int DetailId { get; set; }

    public virtual AppUserDetail UserDetail { get; set; }
}
}
```

[image]

There are so many code blocks that I can not paste here. I would be very happy if someone could help.

If you would like to see the project, you can check here;

https://github.com/dogaanismail/DevPlatform

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been solved by editing AddLinqToDBStores.

```
 public static void AddDevPlatformAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.AddIdentity<AppUser, LinqToDB.Identity.IdentityRole<int>>(options =>
        {
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 4;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;

            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;

            //TODO
            //options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true; 
            //options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
            //options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
            //options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3);

        }).AddLinqToDBStores<int, AppUserClaim, AppUserRole, AppUserLogin, AppUserToken, AppRoleClaim>(new
        IdentityConnectionFactory(new SqlServerDataProvider(ProviderName.SqlServer, SqlServerVersion.v2017), "SqlServerIdentity", DataSettingsManager.LoadSettings().ConnectionString))
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie();

        // Uncomment the following lines to enable logging in with third party login providers

        JwtTokenDefinitions.LoadFromConfiguration(configuration);
        services.ConfigureJwtAuthentication();
        services.ConfigureJwtAuthorization();
    }
```